# Javascript uploading multiple auto generated file forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, file, multipartform-data

In my page I had only one html file input :

```
input type="file" name="file" files-model="service.file" id="filo" accept=".zip" />
```

And I used to get my file to be uploaded in a multi-part file request like this :

```
 var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('file', filo.files[0]);//filo is the id of the input
 //and send my http request having fd as a parameter
```

The problem is that now I have auto generated forms in my page with angular ng-repeat so I can no more get my file using the input ID, how can I do this now ?

Cheers,

Comment: when do you call this `fd.append()`? Provide [plunker](https://plnkr.co) example, please

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit tricky with javascript. [this](http://ng-file-upload) library worked for me. see example below.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
   type="file"
   ngf-select="receiveSlectedFiles($file)">
   Select Logo
</a>
```

whenever you select file, you will get it in **receiveSlectedFiles($file)** function. when user select valid file it will be in $file if not the $file will be null.

example in controller:

```
 var arrayOfFiles = [];
   $scope.receiveSlectedFiles = function (file) {
    if (file) {
        arrayOfFiles.push(file);
    }
};
```

In service, inject **Upload** and then use below code to upload image:

```
this.uploadMultiple = function (files) {
        var uri = yourApiUrl;

        return Upload.upload({
            url: uri,
            arrayKey: '',
            data: {
                files: files
            }
        })
    };
```

in controller, you just need to pass array of files to this service.